# How to know Index of LinearLayout by child View?

Tags: android, android-layout

My layout is like this

```
<ParentLinearlayout>
    <ChildLinearlayout>
       <Button>
    </ChildLinearlayout>
    <ChildLinearlayout>
       <Button>
    </ChildLinearlayout>
</ParentLinearlayout1>
```

Number of ChildLinearlayout is changed ,add and delete dynamically.

When button is clicked, I want to remove ChildLinearlayout which is parent of Button.

but I dont know index linearlayout. index is often changed,therefore cant use tag.

How to know LinearLayout index?

Answer (score 5):

```
int index = linearLayout.indexOfChild(view);
linearLayout.removeViewAt(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another, more robust, method is to assign a tag to each child as you add it to the parent.

```
View child = // TODO
child.setTag("child" + i);
parent.addView(child);
```

And use findViewByTag() to locate it again.

```
parent.removeView(parent.findViewByTag("child4"));
```

Comment: sorry index is change,cant set tag

Answer (score 0):

```
parent.removeView((View)button.getParent());
```

Be careful with this though, as it's very dependant on your View hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void showListofData() {
    if (linearlayout.getChildCount() > 0) {
        linearlayout.removeAllViews();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < mylist.size(); i++) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = null;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View mLinearView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.row, null);

        TextView cName = (TextView) mLinearView
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
        clinicName.setText(mylist.get(i).name);
        mLinearView.setTag(mylist.get(i));
        linearlayout.addView(mLinearView);

        mLinearView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             int pos=(Integer)v.getTag();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should edit your answer and add a description as to why your code works. This is a suggestion to improve this answer and future posts. Thanks!